# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See 'docker run --help'

Tags: linux, docker

I started to learn docker recently. After I install the docker,and I input `sudo docker run hello-world` to check does it install successfully, it shows as the title. By the way,when I input `docker version`, it shows the version that I installed.

Comment: Be aware docker cli != docker daemon, when you ask docker for version - you're working with cli, to connect to docker daemon you have to start daemon first

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you've only installed docker but haven't started the docker daemon. On most distros, you can use `systemctl`:

```sh
sudo systemctl start docker   # to start the service
sudo systemctl enable docker  # to autostart on boot
```

Comment: If I run `sudo systemctl status docker` it tells me the daemon is already running:

`● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-10-25 16:26:12 PDT; 5min ago
` but yet when I run the docker helloworld command I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sometimes add more permissions to /var/run/docker.sock, like that:

```
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**
Check if you have the daemon :

```
sudo systemctl list-units | grep -i docker
```

If you had, check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

**Second**
Start and enable it as @tdy answered.

> ```
> sudo systemctl start docker   # to start the service
> sudo systemctl enable docker  # to autostart on boot
> ```

if you did not have it check [Configure and troubleshoot the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/) for more.

Comment: The code doesnt run, because my ubuntu only can run sysvinit codes rather than systemd, could you write another form of the codes